# LED switching circuit using N-Channel(BSS123) MOSFET

Tags: mosfet-driver

I want to design LED switching circuit using N-Channel(BSS123) MOSFET.  Please find the supply details in the image.

1. What formula can be used to calculate the value of R1?
2. How VDS voltage impact here?  How can find that?  What is the formula for that?

[image]

Comment: R1 * If = 3.3 - Vf. But choose a different mosfet. Find one that has a low Rds. And the Rds should be specified for when Vgs = 3V or lower.

Comment: You should think about formally accepting an answer from one of those below. That's the "fee" on stack exchange to ensure sustained good feedback on your future questions.

Answer (score 3):

Find R1 by using *Ohm's Law*.  That says that the resistance of a resistor is the voltage across it divided by the current thru it.  In common units:

Ω = V / A

You know you want the current to be 70 mA.  You know that the LED drops 2.3 V, and that overall the string of resistor, LED, and switch will drop 3.3 V.  If the switch were perfect, then there would be (3.3 V)-(2.3 V) = 1.0 V across the resistor when the switch is on.  The ideal resistance value in that case would be (1.0 V)/(70 mA) = 14.3 Ω.

The best way to deal with the drop across Q3 is to make sure it is small enough so that you can ignore it.  There are plenty of FETs available for which that would be true.  These MOSFETs don't have a fixed voltage drop, and look more like a resistance when fully on.  That is something you look up in the FET datasheet.  It is usually called R<sub>DSON</sub>, for "Resistance, drain to source, on-state".

The voltage the FET will drop is its R<sub>DSON</sub> times the current thru it (again from Ohm's law).  As long as this is small compared to the total of 1 V available after the LED drop, you can ignore it.

For example, let's say the FET has a maximum R<sub>DSON</sub> of 30 mΩ.  (30 mΩ)(70 mA) = 2.1 mV, which is well below the level at which you can simply ignore it.

There are many MOSFETs available with such low on resistance.  I often use the IRLML2502 in such roles, but that's just one example of many.

Comment: Is 'Ohm's Lay' a play on words? Did you mean 'Ohm's Law'?

Comment: @Mike: Fixed. -

Answer (score 2):

Read the BSS123 [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/BSS123.pdf).

RDS(on) approximately 4.5 Ohms (look at Figure 3)
Expected VDS at 70 mA is shown graphically in  Figure 1

[image]

At 70 mA ID and 4.5 Ohms RDS(on) you would expect VDs --> 315 mV

Your R1 is now easily calculated from Ohms Law.

R1 = V /I

R1 = (3.3 - 0.315 - 2.3) / 0.07 --> 10 Ohms

Your biggest problem may be that RDS(on) will vary device to device and is a significant percentage of R1 ....so your 70 mA may not be all that accurately defined.

There are much better devices available with much lower RDS(on) than the BSS123. They will invariably be much higher power devices, but you are selecting for RDS(on) .....not power capability.

Comment: OP should use a different MOSFET for sure.

Comment: Your calculated answer is correct, but you meant to show division by 0.07 A (70 mA), not 0.7 A.  Also, the units are missing on the left side of your equation.  Dividing two dimensionless values can't result in units of Ohms.

Comment: You still haven't fixed the units error. Again, manipulating a bunch of dimensionless numbers can't ever result in a answer in units of Ohms.

Comment: It's clear what is meant, and I don't intend to fix it ......if you feel strongly pr [pedantic enough about it....you can edit it.

Comment: The equation you show is just plain wrong.  I pointed out the error and gave you opportunity to fix it yourself.  -1 now that you refuse.  Units matter.  I wish I could -1 again for the attitude of dismissing units as pedantic instead of taking them seriously.  If you had given proper units to the current value, you might have noticed the decimal point slip yourself.  This is a terrible example for others to follow, especially newbies that tend to be particularly sloppy with units.  Your attitude is deplorable, and simply has no place in engineering.

Comment: @OlinLathrop. The meaning was clear, you are just being obnoxious.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to learn;

Never select parts or a design until you understand exactly how it works.

**it wont work well with that FET** due to wide tolerance of RdsOn

You need Vgs(th)=1V then Vgs >300% of Vgs(th) >= 3V will work

- i.e. drive at three times turn-on threshold typical minimum for low Rds
- with Vdd= 3.3V your FET may be too weak to switch

  - RdsOn= 1.3 Ω typ to 10 Ω max.
  - @Vgs=4.5V and you only have 3.3 so it is worse.
  - typical graphs are ok for knowing typical curves but ignores tolerance so then design by Max/Min values must be considered.
- at Id=70mA, Vdd=3.3V for unknown R with LED= 2.3V @70mA
- Using KVL:

  - \$V_{dd} = I_d*(R_1 + R_{dsOn} ) + V_{f_~({Red ~LED)}} \tag1\$

So making RdsOn << R1 makes it a simple V drop = I * (R)

3.3V(Vdd)-2.3V(LED)= 1.0V  thus R = 1000mV/70mA = 14.3 ohms

- so \$(R_1 + R_{dsOn})=14.3~\Omega \tag2\$

  - check worst case does not exceed absolute max I for LED at some ambient T  with tolerances on Rds
- not typical
  [image]

  - **Choose FET with Vgs(th)<=1.1V and RdsOn = 0.1 Ω then R= 14.2 +/-10%**
  - check Pd=I^2R for R to choose power rating ~ 2x typical consumption

Answer (score 0):

You will be near-the-knuckle of this working effectively with the BSS123 MOSFET - at 70 mA it will drop about 0.4 volts with a 3 volt gate drive: -

[image]

Maybe with a 3.3 volt gate drive your volt drop might be 0.3 volts.

Anyway, you need at least 2.3 volts across the LED to get 70 mA (according to how I read your schematic) and, with a supply voltage of 3.3 volts minus 0.3 volts for the BSS123, it leaves you with 3 volts as your *effective supply voltage*.

The difference between 2.3 volts and 3 volts has to be soaked up by your series resistor and so it drops 0.7 volts. Given that it supplies 70 mA, this means a resistance of 0.7/0.07 = 10 ohm.